# Wi-Fi: too many "Tx excessive retries" and "Invalid misc"

Tags: wifi, performance, broadcom

I have an old laptop running LXLE (an Ubuntu-based distro) with a Broadcom BCM4311 Wi-Fi card, and although Wi-Fi connection works, data transfer speed is at roughly half of what it should be when connected to an 802.11g wireless network.

I suspect it is because `iwconfig` reports large numbers of "Tx excessive retries" and "Invalid misc" -- tens of both immediately after boot, thousands after an hour of relatively casual use (email, connection to a remote machine via RDP).

The laptop is located near the Wi-Fi AP (ca. 2 m) and `iwconfig` almost always reports 54 Mb/s bitrate. In spite of this, copying a file from an otherwise idle server on the local network runs at ca. 2 MB/s at best.

As for the driver, I am using `b43`. `broadcom-wl` also works; however, I see no improvement over `b43`. IPv6 is disabled, MTU is set to 1492 (determined using http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings ; this value most probably is due to the VDSL internet connection). I also tried to change the network stack configuration ( https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/ ), but that made no difference either.

The Wi-Fi network is operating on channel 5, while the other two networks are both on channel 11 (a scenario that is quite rare these days, I know...). There are no nearby microwave ovens or other equipment capable of causing significant interference.

I never experience such problems in the same LAN (with the same AP) with an even older LXLE laptop containing an Intel Wi-Fi card. This older laptop can easily transfer files from the aforementioned LAN server at 5.5 MB/s over 802.11g, and `iwconfig` reports zero "Tx excessive retries" and "Invalid misc" there.

Is -- perhaps I should write "was" when referencing such ancient hardware -- BCM4311 simply a pain to run under linux without issues? What else can I try to improve the Wi-Fi performance?

Comment: Everything is correct it seems. 802.11g is not per se a speed indicator. 
It usually connects with 54Mbit/s which is about 25Mbit/s net speed (which is then also a bit above 2MB/s when copying). Note that there are proprietary extensions that can double the speed (and still being 802.11g)
Bottom line: 802.11g isn't faster than in your setup (at least not significantly)

Comment: @stoney: Thank you for the clarification. If this were the case also on the other linux laptop, I'd not try to diagnose it at all. What bugs me is the fact that one (and much older to boot) laptop can transfer data over the same Wi-Fi network at a significantly higher speed. I'll try to swap the Wi-Fi card (BCM4311) with an Intel one to see if it helps.